# Need help to execute sed command to replace a string with a variable

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have a variable in data/time format and I want to replace it with the first parameter of below string in a file with the user input variable

```
TO_DATE('07/13/2021 00:30:00' 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I want to replace `'07/13/2021 00:30:00'` with my variable.

I have a script which would take user input for start time and store it in a variable 'st'

I have a sql file which a static query. I need help in replacing TO_DATE('07/13/2021 00:30:00' with the variable and then the script would execute.

Tried below sed command and it's not working

sed -e 's/(*.TO_DATE()[^ ]*( .*)/\1'$st'\2/' /apps/tmp/abc.sql

Getting error message:
Unknown option to `s'
I am new to sed stuff.
I am new to sed stuff

Can someone please help?

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/658362/edit) your question and include your attempts, and how they failed.

Comment: This feels like you're opening up the possibility of sql injection.

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

With sed, you'll want the `s///` command, but beware that the the replacement text contails slashes. You can use different delimiters for the `s` command: here I'll use commas:

```bsh
sed -E "s,(TO_DATE\(')[^']+,\1${timestamp}," file.sql
```

Demo:

```bsh
$ cat file.sql
select * from table1
where created > TO_DATE('07/13/2021 00:30:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

$ timestamp=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y %T')

$ sed -E "s,(TO_DATE\(')[^']+,\1${timestamp}," file.sql
select * from table1
where created > TO_DATE('07/14/2021 10:46:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

The keys here are to use double quotes for the sed body to allow the shell to expand the variable, and to choose different delimiters for `s///`

And as commented, thoroughly validate the contents of the variable to keep out [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Thank you very very much Glenn. It worked for me. Appreciate your quick help!!

Comment: Hi Jhalak, if glenn's answer worked for you, maybe you should mark his answer as accepted?

Comment: Thanks for the backup, but a user with 1 rep and 1 question from 2021 is unlikely to see your comment.